# Xquery group by on 2 tags

Tags: xquery, basex

Below is the XML part of my data.

```
<A>
 <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Banana</Name></a>
 <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Orange</Name></a>
 <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Apple</Name></a>
 <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Lemon</Name></a>
 <a><Type>Cars</Type><Name>Toyota</Name></a>
 <a><Type>Cars</Type><Name>Lamborghini</Name></a>
 <a><Type>Cars</Type><Name>Renault</Name></a>
</A>
```

Out put as -

```
<a>Fruits-Banana,Orange,Apple,Lemon</a>
<a>Cars-Toyota,Lamborghini,Renault</a>
```

I tried to get the required output by all in vain. I tried 'group by` clause too, but getting errors.

any help?

Comment: @Pratik- what error are you getting with 'group by` clause? Next time please mention the errors and the code which you tried. So that we can help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let $x:=
<A>
  <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Banana</Name></a>
  <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Orange</Name></a>
  <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Apple</Name></a>
  <a><Type>Fruit</Type><Name>Lemon</Name></a>
  <a><Type>Cars</Type><Name>Toyota</Name></a>
  <a><Type>Cars</Type><Name>Lamborghini</Name></a>
  <a><Type>Cars</Type><Name>Renault</Name></a>
</A>

  for $z in distinct-values($x//a/Type)
    let $c := $x//a[Type=$z]/Name
    return
       <a>{concat($z, "-", string-join($c, ","))}</a>
```

First `for` is taking the distinct values of the tag `Type`, then for each distinct value of this, the respective values of all the `Name` tags are derived.

Then using the `concat` function I have concatenated the `Type` text with the string generated by `string-join`, used to add/append the `Name` and `,` (comma).

HTH :)

Comment: Nice approach, with XQuery 1.0 at that.  The `return` on the line following the `for` isn't strictly necessary; I'd suggest removing it.

Comment: You can try this query live at http://try.zorba.io/queries/xquery/ZTtNrwgVmveyFtwk7Moon92cRMM%3D

Comment: @joewiz- thanks for pointing it out :) Updated now without that `return`